# Rolling Averages sheets in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I'm collating a document for a Daily Production report at work, in which every day, a new tab is added and the information on part production from each department for the previous day is recorded. The data is then added to a rolling average sheet, which displays the cumulative results for all previous entries. I was wondering if anyone knows a way that I could have Excel add the next day's information on automatically each time a new sheet is added? The sheet is duplicated from a template sheet that already contains all the summing formulae required for the sheet to function. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: 1.) Excel is not a database. 2.) Why are you creating a new sheet every day? Why not just append to the existing sheet, and have a Date column to distinguish between days? That would make a *lot* of things a lot easier to do, if you're stuck in Excel. It seems like you're already doing both, so why not just do the one and be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directions for an example, revealing the tools for a possible way to do this.

Pick up a blank sheet
Type a set of random numbers into 5-10 cells in column A
In B1, type "Sum", 
in B2, type =sum(A1:A100)
Yes that is fixed rows and does not adapt, it is there so you will see that it works

Now to begin to build something interesting
In C1 type "SubTotal"
In C2 type =subtotal(3,A1:A100)

In D1 type "Built-ref"
In D2 type =CELL("address",A1)&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,C2-1,0))

in E1 type "Sum-thru-ref"
In E2 type =SUM(INDIRECT(D2))

Now: 
Excel accepts "A:A" as a reference/replacement for "A1:A100" above, in Excel that is all of column A. I am using LibreOffice, which does not accept it.

Column B is there to allow checking the resul

Cell C2 tells how many cells there are that has values in them. 
Look up SUBTOTAL() to see what it counts, there are other options that you might find very useful.

Cell D2 contains two calls to CELL() which with the given "address" will create a string consisting of a fixed address to the reference cell (also array in Excel?) you provide as second argument.
As you can see there are two of these, the second creates a reference using the OFFSET() function, allowing a calculation be used to find the cell you wish to reference. 
Add the concatenations and you have a valid array reference...

... which then can be used via INDIRECT() as in cell E2

With this built, if you type in a new number in the list in column A, then the reference in cell D2 will get automatically updated.
That fact will be the basis for all formulas in e.g. a rolling average...

Now, for a rolling average (or anything!) - I would do the dynamics used for the END of the list here, also for the BEGINNING of the list.

HTH

--- Untitled.csv ---

```
10,"sum","subtot","Built-ref","Sum-thru-ref"
9,"=SUM(A1:A100)","=SUBTOTAL(3,A1:A100)","=CELL(""address"",A1)&"":""&CELL(""address"",OFFSET(A1,C2-1,0))","=SUM(INDIRECT(D2))"
8,,,,
7,,,,
6,,,,
15,,,,
4,,,,
3,,,,
3,,,,
2,,,,
1,,,,
```